# Ordering four real numbers such that some conditions are satisfied

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

Suppose I have 4 real numbers in $[0,1]$, all different between each other.

**Assume that** there exists a way of ordering the four numbers such that: 
$$
\begin{cases}
w_1>w_2\\
w_3=1-w_1\\
w_4=1-w_2
\end{cases}
$$
where $w_1$ is the first number in the ordered sequence, $w_2$ is the second number in the ordered sequence, $w_3$ is the third number in the ordered sequence, $w_4$ is the fourth number in the ordered sequence.

Is such a way of ordering **unique**? If yes, could you sketch the proof? In not, could you give a counterexample?

Comment: What exactly do you mean when you say unique?

Comment: can you give such an assignment to the following four numbers? $\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{8},\frac{1}{16},\frac{1}{32}$

Comment: @Suraj: I'm assuming that such an assignment exists. My assignment requires that you can construct two pairs summing up to 1. In your example, this is not possible.

Comment: @AnkitKumar I mean that you cannot have two different assignments satisfying the constraints I gave.

Comment: I am sure that such an assignment is not possible with the four reals given below. So that serves as an counterexample. All four reals are less than $\frac{1}{2}$ so you cannot have sum of any two equal to $1$.

Comment: @Suraj: I'm focusing on the cases where the 4 real numbers admits such an assignment and I want to show that IF that is the case THEN this assignment is unique. As a counterexample, you should provide 4 numbers admitting TWO assignments satisfying my constraints.

Comment: Oh, I got it now

Comment: What do you mean by assigning a label to a real number?

Comment: @ancientmathematician Maybe I used the wrong terminology. What I mean is: suppose you have four real numbers and it is possible to order them in a way such that (A) the first number in the ordered sequence is $>$ then the second number in the ordered sequence (B) the first number  in the ordered sequence plus the third number in the ordered sequence gives $1$ (C) the second number  in the ordered sequence plus the fourth number in the ordered sequence gives $1$.

Comment: What about $0,\frac{1}{4},\frac{3}{4}, 1$ and $\frac{1}{4},1,0,\frac{3}{4}$? [I choose to do $w_1<w_2$ and swap $w_3$ and $w_4$ it's the same thing.]

Comment: I see. Do I avoid this if I impose that all the four real numbers are in $(0,1)$ (instead of $[0,1]$)?

Comment: No. Think about it.